# Duplicate Header and Footer

Tags: customization, headers, footer

I am creating a new page template and also need to create a duplicate header and footer php template to use with the new page template.

I have already duplicated each php file and named them header-2.php and footer-2.php.
I also updated the new page template code to get_header('2'); and get_footer('2');.

The main header and footer links can be updated in the Dashboard (Appearance > Menus).
How do I now edit the duplicated header and footer with new content/links/logo?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well you developed them. What code did you put in them to allow those things to be edited?

Comment: I did not develop them; they came with the theme

Comment: Open files with code editor and change the links etc. Or you can use acf and call this new Fields into duplicated files.